# Error HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure .Net Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de subir un proyecto al IIS pero me sale este error de que entra al developer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estuve leyendo que se necesitaba cambiar la configuracion en el web config como lo muestra en esta respuesta [ErrorDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab) y te da el error directo.

```
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Application.exe" arguments=".\FotoConMarcelo.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
```

cambiando el valor de `value="Development"` a `value="Production"`

Ahora me salio este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve investigando el error y me sale que es por no tener instalado el `.NET Core Runtime 2.2`. Ya lo instale y sigue con el mismo error.
Alguien sabe por que ?

Comment: Tienes que ir a los logs del IIS para ver las razones del fallo. Pueden ser muchas otras. Intenta detener el proceso en el task manager, y luego iniciar el `Proyecto.exe` directamente en el IIS y ver qué dice la consola de comandos.